# return value when this code was perform

Tags: steganography

```
int red = colorvalue >> 2;// why use this expression
colorvalue -= red << 2;

int colorValue = messageLength;
int red = colorValue >> 2;
colorValue -= red << 2;
int green = colorValue >> 1;
int blue = colorValue - (green << 1);
pixelColor = Color.FromArgb(red, green, blue);
bitmap.SetPixel(0,0, pixelColor);
```

Please explain it for me. I don't understand the algorithm.  Why use this expression: `colorvalue -= red << 2;` ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the "<<" and ">>" operators are bitwise operators for shifting. You can find plenty of info about these operations on the net by searching for the "bitwise operator" keywords.

Basically what you're doing is shifting the *colorvalue* variable by two bits, which means you're dividing *colorvalue* by 4 and storing in the *red* variable.

Afterwards, what the code does is subtracting from *colorvalue* the variable stored in the *red* variable multiplied by 4.

> int red = colorvalue >> 2; // why use this expression
>
> colorvalue -= red << 2;

**The code works as a modulo operation where the function divisor is 4 and the dividend is *colorvalue***.